# wp_localize_script -> need to pass "[0,6]" to JS

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am working on a plugin. I use "wp_localize_script" to pass variables to JS. All in all I'm passing 16 variables. All of them work, except one and I need assistance to get it work...

Originally the JS-code-line would look like this:

```
hiddenDays: [0,6],
```

If I configure the variable in PHP statically like this, the variable gets passed to JS fine:

```
$settings = array(
  'hiddenDays' => [0,6]
);

wp_localize_script( 'settings', 'js_x_vars' , $settings );
```

Now I try it somehow like this:

```
$db_value = "0,6"; // Would originally be retrieved from database
$hiddendays = "[" . $db_value . "]";

$settings = array(
  'hiddenDays' => $hiddendays
);

wp_localize_script( 'settings', 'js_x_vars' , $settings );
```

This doesn't work and I tried a lot of similar variations. I also tried to set the brackets in JS and pass only the numbers ...

In Browser-source I see, that there is a unwanted line-break:
[image: Source]

**EDIT:**
As recommended I have tried now to pass the Array directly like this:

```
$db_value = "0,6"; // Would originally be retrieved from database

$settings = array(
  'hiddenDays' => array($db_value)
);

wp_localize_script( 'settings', 'js_x_vars' , $settings );
```

This doesn't work either ...
It would be working like this:

```
'hiddenDays' => array(0,6)
```

**EDIT2:**
As recommended I have also tried to pass it as actual Array:

```
$db_value = "0,6";
$db_value = explode(',', $db_value);
$settings = array(
   'hiddenDays' => $db_value
);
```

This doesn't work either and results in the following:

[image: array]

**EDIT3:**
My JS Knowledge is very limited and I am not able to debug in JS. I managed to output a console.log(js_x_vars.hiddenDays). I think this could be helpful. Please have a look at the following Image:

[image: console.log]

How to get around this?

Thank you

Comment: You can try to pass the array directly. Double bracket means that is an array. In wp_localize_script : 'hiddenDays'=>array(0,6). And get it in the js : js_x_vars.hiddenDays;

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work either ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out on my own ...

Building the array as recommended with explode:

```
$db_value = "0,6";
$db_value = explode( ',', $db_value );
```

The Result of "var_dump( $dbvalue )":

**array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "0" [1]=> string(1) "6" }**

---

Now the solution:

```
$db_value = "0,6";
$db_value = array_map( 'intval', explode( ',', $db_value ) );
```

The Result of "var_dump( $dbvalue )":

**array(2) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(6) }**

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're passing a string, not an array. What you need to do is explode that string from db by `,` which will turn your string into an actual array

```
$db_value = "0,6";
$db_value = explode(',', $db_value); 
$settings = array(
    'hiddenDays' => $db_value // equals to two element array with 0 and 6 as elements
);
```

Comment: I had the same idea before, but it doesn't work either. Please have a look at EDIT2 above.

Comment: Is it actual line break or is it just word wrap? Also, have you tried to access it via JS after outputting it this way?

Comment: My JS Knowledge is limited and it is very hard for me to debug in JS. I have managed to get a consle.log of the variable. Please have a look at EDIT3 above. Thank you.

Comment: so what exactly is your problem? why is it not ok if you got an array?

Comment: The JS expects this option as " [ 0,6 ] ". https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/hiddenDays/
If you can help me to convert the array in JS to the expected format it would be great. I would like it more to control this in PHP, but if it is not possible ...

Comment: what you have from this solution is what js expects. JS expects an array and that's exactly what you're getting from this solution. All you have to do is assign it like `hiddenDays: js_x_vars.hiddenDays`

Comment: As mentioned i am passing 16 variables. All are working except of this one. Of course I have assigned it.